# RecyclerView.ItemDecoration doesn't update after item is removed from RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

### My question

How can I get my `ItemDecoration` to "update" the item offsets for *other* views when I remove a given view from my adapter and then call `notifyItemRemoved()` ?

In my particular situation, I have an `ItemDecoration` that provides a small amount of **top** offset to every item, and a large amount of **bottom** offset to *the last item only*. When I remove the last item, the view that *becomes the new last item* does not have any bottom offset.

Before and after:

[image]
[image]

If I then scroll the list around, when I return to the bottom of the list, my "new" last item has the correct offsets. It's only an issue for as long as the "new" last item remains visible on the screen.

### What I've tried

If I change my `notifyItemRemoved()` call to `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the new last item will have the correct item offsets applied, but I lose the built-in animation I get from `notifyItemRemoved()`.

If I keep using `notifyItemRemoved()` and *additionally* call `notifyItemChanged()` on the previous item, then I will get the correct item offsets but the animation is somewhat janky; the second-to-last item (before the removal) seems to fade out and then in again (in this screenshot, the card saying "item 19" was just removed):

[image]

I know that I can create a large space at the end of my list by applying bottom padding to my `<RecyclerView>` tag and specifying `android:clipToPadding="false"`, but this solution is not acceptable for various reasons.

### To reproduce

I originally encountered this issue in a much larger app I'm working on, but here's a tiny app that demonstrates the issue.

MainActivity.java:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(20);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            adapter.removeItemAt(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        }
    });

    RecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recycler.addItemDecoration(new MyItemDecoration());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private static class MyItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int viewPosition = parent.getChildViewHolder(view).getLayoutPosition();
        int lastPosition = state.getItemCount() - 1;

        outRect.top = 20;
        outRect.bottom = (viewPosition == lastPosition) ? 200 : 0;
    }
}

private static class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    private final List<String> list;

    private MyAdapter(int count) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            list.add("" + i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.text.setText("item: " + list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    private void removeItemAt(int position) {
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            list.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
}

private static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView text;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```html
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#eee">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REMOVE LAST ITEM"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I solved this by changing my `removeItemAt()` method as follows:

```
private void removeItemAt(int position) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);

        if (position != 0) {
            notifyItemChanged(position - 1, Boolean.FALSE);
        }
    }
}
```

The second argument to `notifyItemChanged()` is the key. It can be literally any object, but I chose `Boolean.FALSE` because it's a "well-known" object and because it conveys a little bit of intent: I don't want animations to run on the item I'm changing.

### Why it works

It turns out that there's a second `onBindViewHolder()` method defined in `RecyclerView.Adapter` that I'd never seen before. From the source code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
}
```

Excerpted from that method's documentation:

> The `payloads` parameter is a merge list from `notifyItemChanged(int, Object)` or `notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int, Object)`.  If the `payloads` list is not empty, the `ViewHolder` is currently bound to old data and `Adapter` may run an efficient partial update using the payload info.  If the payload is empty,  `Adapter` must run a full bind.

In other words, by passing something (anything) as a payload in `notifyItemChanged()`, we're telling the system that we want to perform only a "partial update" (in situations where that's possible).

So, sure, we've instructed the system to perform a partial update... but how does that stop the flickering caused by simply calling `notifyItemChanged(position - 1)` ? It has to do with the `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator` that's attached to all `RecyclerView`s by default: `DefaultItemAnimator`.

`DefaultItemAnimator`'s source code includes this method:

```
@Override
public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder,
        @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    return !payloads.isEmpty() || super.canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder, payloads);
}
```

You'll notice that this method also takes a `List<Object> payloads` parameter. This is the same list of payloads as used in the other `onBindViewHolder()` call mentioned above.

Because we passed a payload argument, this method will return `true`. And since the animator is now told that it can **reuse** the already-existing `ViewHolder` for our "changed" item, it doesn't tear it down and create a new one (or reuse a recycled one)... which stops the default fade animation on the changed item from running!

Comment: Thank you for this!
I had a slightly different problem related to removing an item: ItemDecoration was being applied to an item I just removed. Adding the `notifyItemChanged` even without the payload fixed that.

Comment: You, sir, are a legend! I had issues with margins setup via `ItemDecoration` not being applied after DiffUtils calculates and propagates the changes. Using `notifyItemChanged` in `AdapterUpdateCallback` for all the actions solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This is a too late answer, but I will answer because I have the same problem. Try call RecyclerView.invalidateItemDecorations() before insert/update/remove data.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to make sure the call to `invalidateItemDecorations()` comes _after_ the update

Answer (score 14):

**ListAdapter** solution:

```
listAdapter.submitList(newList) {
    handler.post { // or just "post" if you're inside View
        recyclerView.invalidateItemDecorations()
    }
}
```

The key is new `submitList(list, commitCallback)` method from latest RecyclerView release. It allows you to call `invalidateItemDecorations()` **after** ListAdapter will apply all changes to RecyclerView.

I also had to add `post {}` call to make it work - without it decorations invalidated too early, and nothing happens.

Comment: Quite frustrating it needs to be forced like this and with that additional `post` but at the end it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although Ben has given the right solution, that doesn't cover the use case of people who are using `ListAdapter` because the use of `AsyncListDiffer` inside that class only notifies the exact changes. So for that to happen, I have written my own class.

```kotlin
abstract class BetterListAdapter<T, VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
    private val diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    private lateinit var listDiffer: AsyncListDiffer<T>

    val currentList: List<T> get() = listDiffer.currentList

    init {
        val notifier = ListUpdateAdapterNotifier()
        val config = AsyncDifferConfig.Builder(diffCallback).build()

        listDiffer = AsyncListDiffer(notifier, config)
        listDiffer.addListListener(this::onCurrentListChanged)
    }

    fun submitList(items: List<T>, commitCallback: Runnable? = null): Unit =
        listDiffer.submitList(items, commitCallback)

    fun getItem(position: Int): T =
        currentList[position]

    override fun getItemCount(): Int =
        currentList.size

    fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: List<T>, currentList: List<T>) =
        Unit

    private inner class ListUpdateAdapterNotifier : ListUpdateCallback {

        private val lastPosition: Int get() = itemCount - 1

        override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count)

            if (position > 1) {
                notifyItemChanged(position - 1, false)
            }

            if (position < lastPosition) {
                notifyItemChanged(position + count + 1, false)
            }
        }

        override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count)

            if (position > 1) {
                notifyItemChanged(position - 1, false)
            }

            notifyItemChanged(position, false)
        }

        override fun onMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)

            notifyItemChanged(fromPosition, false)
            notifyItemChanged(toPosition, false)

            if (fromPosition > 1) {
                notifyItemChanged(fromPosition - 1, false)
            }

            if (fromPosition < lastPosition) {
                notifyItemChanged(fromPosition + 1, false)
            }

            if (toPosition > 1) {
                notifyItemChanged(toPosition - 1, false)
            }

            if (toPosition < lastPosition) {
                notifyItemChanged(toPosition + 1, false)
            }
        }

        override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int, payload: Any?) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count, payload)
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your codebase, just extend your adapter from `BetterListAdapter` instead of `ListAdapter` and it will notify changes in neighbouring views automatically.

Since I have custom spacings implemented as an `ItemDecoration` and they differ depending on the neighbouring cells, this will now properly update my spacings.

Thanks for the original answer Ben!